# How do i make a stickman's arms reach out to the mouse cursor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Stickman

[image: 1]

I have this stickman here in unity 2D and i want his arms to always reach out to the direction of the mouse. I have no ideas on where i should start and i'm hoping someone here could help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Foremost, you need to determine the mouse position. It can be done with the following method:

```
public Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition()
{
    Vector3 mouseScreenPosition = UnityEngine.Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouseScreenPosition);
    return mouseWorldPosition;
}
```

I use  `Camera.main` here for demonstration purposes. In sake of performance it will be better to cache it as a field in your class.

Now, when you have the target coordinates, you can rotate the hand. Here is an example method:

```
public void RotateLimb()
{
    Vector3 rotationTargetPosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
    Vector3 directionVector = (rotationTargetPosition - _limb.transform.position).normalized;
    float angleInRad = Mathf.Atan2(directionVector.y, directionVector.x);
                
    Vector3 targetAngle = _limb.transform.eulerAngles;
    targetAngle.z = angleInRad * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                
    _limb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetAngle);
}
```

Method `RotateLimb()` can be called in `Update` or a coroutine.

All the variables of this method can also be stored as private fields in your class.

`_limb` must contain `Transform` of your hand GameObject and you can assign it as SerializeField

```
[SerializeField] private Transform _limb;
```

`_limb` will rotate around its pivot. Therefore, pivot must be in the center of the shoulder. In order to achieve it, you can place all the graphics of your hand as a child of `_limb` and adjust it accordingly.

This seems like the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: i tried it but the ragdoll's limbs end up always falling to the floor and rotating, while the arm connected to it is stuck in a fixed rotation